# Are fact and opinion mutually exclusive?

Tags: meaning

If I believe a fact, is that fact also my opinion? I'd always thought that opinion and fact are mutually exclusive. To me, 1+1=2 cannot be considered an opinion, as it is a fact.

Merriam-Webster has a few definitions of the word *opinion*, including one that seems to suggest that facts could also be considered opinions:

> a view, judgment, or appraisal formed in the mind about a particular matter

and one that seems to support the idea that fact and opinion are mutually exclusive:

> belief stronger than impression and less strong than positive knowledge

Comment: That depends on you. your philosophy of life and your religious persuasion. Some believe religious opinions and beliefs are facts.

Comment: This site may be a more appropriate for this question: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sadly it is my opinion that your assertion is a fact @Josh61

Comment: Why is this question closed? I think it is a very good question. The question linked does not even uses the word "opinion". Is there a way to vote against this decision?

Comment: @JJMDriessen Yes you can vote to reopen if you have enough rep, you may also like to contribute to the discussion on this question here: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7127/voted-to-reopen-due-to-incorrect-closure-reason

Answer (score 0):

If a dictionary gives more than one meaning for a word then that indicates the word is used by different people at different times to mean different things. Therefore if you wish to conduct, say, a philosophical discussion about fact versus opinion, it is up to you to choose which definition suits your purpose. Then  you should state clearly what *you* mean by the terms before continuing with your essay.

As Blessed Geek implies, different people have different ideas about what constitutes an opinion or a fact. René Descartes came to the conclusion that there was only one true fact that he could be certain of. He summed it up in his famous phrase *[je pense, donc je suis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito_ergo_sum)* (also formulated as *cogito ergo sum* and *I think therefore I am*).

Comment: http://www.metrolyrics.com/the-philosophers-song-lyrics-monty-python.html

Answer (score 0):

No they are not mutually exclusive.

Consider a "fact", let us say "there are an infinite number of prime numbers", for the purposes of this let us agree that this *is* a true statement but you don't know whether it is true or not.

Now. Do you believe this statement? Let us say that you don't believe it. That is your opinion but the fact you don't believe it has no bearing on whether it is true or not (we have already agreed it is a true "fact").

Then suppose a mathematician instructs you in the arcane knowledge of how to *prove* it is true (note, I have no idea whether it actually is or not in real life :) and you follow the logic and come to see that that proof shows you it is true. You must therefore change you opinion from "I don't believe" to "I do believe". Note that nothing about the underlying truth of the conjecture has changed- only your opinion has changed.

Now you have a true "fact" and also your opinion that it is true. Since one can change without affecting the state of the other they are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: But what makes a belief about something of which the truth is unknown an opinion? If someone believes in cookie monster, is it then their opinion that it exists? I don't think that it's justified to interchange the words belief and opinion.

Comment: But I have not interchanged them, I have implied that a belief that something is so must always lead to, and be equivalent to, an opinion that it is so. This is semantics. I contend that if someone believes the Cookie Monster *exists* then it IS their opinion that it exists. Your question makes no sense as it mixes meanings (i.e. 'Belief in the Cookie Monster' (whatever that means) and 'Opinion [or belief] the Cookie Monster exists)

Comment: I think that the struggle lies in that contention exactly. Belief and opinion are fundamentally different. Let me illustrate it with another example. If I say, "I believe that I am going to fail this exam", does this then imply "It is my opinion that I am going to fail this exam"? Does the latter even make sense?

Comment: I would answer "yes the former implies the latter" and I also contend that it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great question.

In my opinion, a fact and opinion are mutually exclusive if we limit it to one person's perspective.

But as others have suggested, if we talk about opinions and facts of different people, they are not really exclusive, because facts for some people are just opinions for others.